# new picture not registering

Tags: html, css, image

first time poster and html noob here.

For a few hours now ive been trying to use a background picture. I downloaded an image I wanted to use, and set about trying to code it.

No matter what I tried, the image would not display. However, when I tried one of the other images I was using, it displayed just fine.

I tried using just the first letter of the existing image, and the program immediately suggested the image in a dropdown, as well as several other images with names starting with the same letter. However when I tried to use the new images first letter, it did list options, but none of them were the image I had downloaded.

I tried renaming the image, but still no luck.

I havnt included any code just yet, since this seems to not be related to the code itself (Since other images display just fine). Has anyone run into something like this before? Extensive google searches did not yeild anything for me.

In case it matters, I am specifying the background image as part of the Body css.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which is the format of the image? Is it supported in you browser?

Comment: what do you mean "the program immediatly suggested the image in a dropdown", What program ??

Comment: I think if you post the html it would make the question clearer. At a guess, it's most likely an issue with where the image is located on the hdd vs where you html is expecting to be.

Answer (score 0):

Please check to ensure your preferred image is located in the same parent folder as your htlm.

Answer (score 0):

As @Patrick Falvey says but if the picture is not in the same folder remeber to / before your file path :)